# Merging two figures in one using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I scripted two interaction plots that I'd like to merge into the one same plot. I'm a beginner to R so I hope this question is still interesting.

Below is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(arm)

df <- tibble::tribble(~Proportion, ~Lower,~Upper, ~LGCA,
                      invlogit(-0.9417583), invlogit(-1.394725916), invlogit(-0.488790684), "Day",
                      invlogit(-0.1771685), invlogit(-0.630136116) ,invlogit(0.275799116), "Night")
df


dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(ymin = Proportion - Lower,
         ymax = Proportion + Upper)

p <-   ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = LGCA, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, stroke = 0, shape = 16,color="darkgoldenrod2") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=Proportion, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper),color="darkgoldenrod2",width=0.1,size=1)


p<-p+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
           axis.title=element_text(size=20))
p





df <- tibble::tribble(~Proportion, ~Lower,~Upper, ~SNP,
                      invlogit(-0.2486022), invlogit(-0.654304025), invlogit(0.157099625), "Day",
                      0.6878081, ( 0.6878081-0.0961473) ,(0.6878081+ 0.0961473), "Night")
df


dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(ymin = Proportion - Lower,
         ymax = Proportion + Upper)

p <-   ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = SNP, y = Proportion)) +
  geom_point(size = 6, stroke = 0, shape = 16,color="coral") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=Proportion, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper),color="coral",width=0.1,size=1)


p<-p+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
           axis.title=element_text(size=20))
p
```

The new single interaction plot will have `ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Time, y = Proportion))` as axis labels, and a colored legend specifying what the points represent:

For `color="darkgoldenrod2"` that is `LGCA` and for `color="coral"` that is `SNP`.

I also would like to add a dotted line connecting both points of the same color, but I'm unsure on how this can be done.

Anyway, I hope somebody can at least put me on the right track.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way that I use is to create the two plots and save them at my global environment, i.e. `plot1`, `plot2`, and then I use `grid.arrange` from package `gridExtra`. For example, a line from my actual code is: `grid.arrange(overall_comp_plots[[1]], overall_comp_plots[[2]], overall_comp_plots[[3]], ncol = 3, widths = c(3, 2, 1.5))`

Comment: You need to put all your data in one data.frame with column `Proportion, Lower, Upper, Variable, Value` where `Variable` is `"SNP"` or `"LGCA"` and `Value` the corresponding value. This will allow you to use `aes(color = Variable)` in your ggplot (to get a single plot with the 2 datasets and 2 colors).

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for your answer. I've used your line code as follows with my two renamed plots `p1` and `p2`: `grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 3, widths = c(3, 2, 1.5))`. However, this command line is not combining both plots as I explained above, but only displaying one next to the other.

Comment: @antoine-sac Thank you for your answer. Yes indeed, that worked very well and now I have all points into one same plot. However, now I'm unsure on how the `aes(color=Variable)` needs to be implemented from my original line: ```p <-   ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Value, y = Proportion)) +

  geom_point(size = 6, stroke = 0, shape = 16,color="coral") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=Proportion, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper),color="coral",width=0.1,size=1)```, as now all points have color `"coral"`

Comment: Remove `color = "coral"` (which hardcodes all points to coral) and add `color = Variable` in your ggplot `aes` (next to `x = Value, y = Proportion`). This will use the default color palette (blue and red), if you want to use a custom palette (coral and gold), you need to tweak the `scale_color_discrete` or `scale_color_manual`... See `?scale_color_manual` or search on SO :)

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought that was what you wanted to do :)